# How do I animate the following lines in matplotlib using my `ndarray`?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following function to generate a brownian motion:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import uniform, norm

def walk(n):
    angle = uniform.rvs( size=(n,), loc=.0, scale=2.*np.pi )
    r = norm.rvs( size=n )
    x = np.cumsum( r * np.cos(angle) )
    y = np.cumsum( r * np.sin(angle) )
    return np.array((x, y, r, angle))
```

If I call this like `brownian = walk(1000)`, and plot it like `ax.plot( brownian[0,:], brownian[1,:], color='k')`, it plots it correctly, but now I want to animate it and do this (taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/cipher982/e713b76df64d3918c1119a0ff2cdd091)):

```py
# Length of array (or how long motion is modeled)
motionLength = 1000
        
# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
xyMin = brownian.min() * 1.2
xyMax = brownian.max() * 1.2
plt.axis('equal')
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(xyMin,xyMax), ylim=(xyMin,xyMax))

line, = plt.plot([], [], lw=1, color='k')

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def iterr(i):
    line.set_data(brownian[:i,0],brownian[[:i,1]) # problem here?
    return line,

        
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, iterr, init_func=init, frames=motionLength, 
                               interval=100, blit=True)

anim.save('test_animation_2.mp4', fps=120, bitrate=-1,
          extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
```

But I cannot seem to get it to work. I guess the problem lies in my building the lists in `iterr`, because either 1) I'm not taking the correct values with my slices, or 2) I'm not getting getting from `walk` what I think I'm getting.

How do I rewrite `iterr` to work with my `ndarray`.

Comment: You have the order of the indices mixed up. It needs to be `line.set_data(brownian[0, :i], brownian[1, :i])``. (Also note that this line in the question's code has a superfluous square bracket.)